# Native memory Vs Java application memory

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

I am relatively new to Android application development/memory management in android.

I am aware that Android allocates certain amount of memory for each application.
Is this include natively allocated memory also?

If it is so how does Android track natively allocated memories..

On the other hand if native memory is not a part of this allotted memory, then what will be the maximum limit I can allocate in native?

Please help.... needed for image computations for higher resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

The Android OS lets your application use a certain amount of memory that must be at least 16 MB (for devices that are to be "certified" as Android compatible). You can check the minimum values for each version [here](http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html), in each PDF under the in **Virtual Machine Compatibility** section.

The memory available for your app includes both native and VM (virtual machine) allocated memory (eg. if you use 8MB of native memory, only 8 MB of memory will be available in the VM for your application - considering the minimum of 16MB).

If you **need** to use more memory than that, you can turn on the `largeHeap` flag for your application in `AndroidManifest.xml`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap) is the documentation for it; it also tells you how to query the OS for the available memory at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the information... that helped to an extent. But help me understand how can VM track natively allocated memory.

Comment: I don't know *how* Android does that. It might be a custom `alloc` implementation, it might be the kernel tracking `alloc`s made and the VM querying the kernel for the allocated memory or it might be some other mechanism (like getting the total memory used by all your app's processes and subtracting the memory footprint of the VM from that). You can dig into the Android source code to find this out, but it might take you a while to locate the code doing that (it should be a fun read though).

Comment: I would like to add more... I now checked allocating a malloc of 500 MB in native, it did not give me out of memory error. How is it possible if memory is being tracked?

Comment: Hmm... that's a bit weird. It depends a lot on how Android is built for the specific device that you are using. Afaik, allocating native memory should count against your app's memory limit. I'm developing a picture rich application and, when testing it in the beginning, allocating a lot of bitmaps did cause an OOM error. What did `malloc` return in your native code? If it didn't return `null`, did you try filling the pointer that it returned (or at least an element toward the end of the allocated memory)?

Comment: Forgot to add in the previous comment: I was testing on Android 2.3, which doesn't store bitmap pixel data in the VM heap and the bitmap data size was counted against the total application memory (even if not clearly visible when debugging with MAT)

Comment: yes i did check for the case where malloc failed but the call was successful.

Comment: the doc saied the manifest only set large `Dalvik heap`, the native memory may not included.